# Can nature create codes and specified complexity?

Tags: evolution

Is there an example of nature creating codes or specified complexity? It is said by Creationists that codes can only come from minds, and since DNA has a code, it was created by a mind.

Is this true? If false, can you explain how unguided, unintelligent nature could create coded specified information? Just as a note to show where I'm coming from, I am an Evolutionist.

But I have to admit, this appears to be a very, very strong argument in favor of special creation by an intelligence.

Comment: The problem here is: How do you define nature? At what step is something "Natural" as opposed to "Divine"? Is there a difference the further down you go?

Comment: Simple answer: Creationism is belief, not science. So they claim things, but not set up a hypothesis which can be falsified or proven (which is the way science is doing this kind of thing). And by the way: Why can't nature develop codes? DNA, proteins and many more examples proof that its happening.

Comment: I do not have time to write a proper answer right now, but "codes can only come from minds" seems like an inaccurate and arbitrary statement - which makes it unscientific. For example, how should we define a mind? And what sort of evidence would support or contradict this statement?

Comment: Add references to your question. Statements like; "*It is said by Creationists that codes can only come from minds...*" are far from obvious and you need to back them up with a logical argument or a source making such an argument. As it stands, the question is just an empty statement that includes poorly defined terms (*mind*, *specified complexity*).

Comment: I'll vote for closing your question unless it is made scientific. I really don't see any reason why "a code can only comes from mind". If you can provide any scientific argument in this sense, then we'll be able to discuss the question. Note: you'll need to define what you mean by "mind"

Comment: @LotusBiology I recommend that you take some time and have a look at [Understanding Evolution by UC Berkeley](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01). It is fast and very introductory and you will learn a lot faster. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

If you think of laws of nature as being codes, then we've found many instances of such codes that are in some sense not man-made. Of course, you could say that they are of "divine creation" or some such thing, but then you'll probably be ready to label everything seemingly intelligent, interesting or found as such. So let's not go there! These laws can be seen as codes, albeit not intentionally created ones.